# What use is the water pistol?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I have unlocked the Water Pistol after completing the right side objective of the right main mission.

Now that I have it, it seem to have unlimited ammo, but just blind for 2 ~ 3 sec the Mother Base guard if I headshot them.

Out of holding up, is there any use to this weapon? Or is it a joke weapon like the Banana was in Peace Walker?

Comment: The game doesn't take itself very seriously. There are a lot of jokes in it, like the chicken head or the porn box which can distract guards ... so i'd say the weapon is only there for fun.

Comment: It seems it is more than a joke weapon, that s what I thought :)

Comment: Wow, made it in the HNQ, didn t expect that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The waterpistol has some uses:

- Can hold up enemy soldiers
- Can be used to distract soldiers. Shoot on the ground/wall near a guard and they will investigate the sound.
- Can extinguish fire. Useful to extinguish those barrel-fires
- Can be used to clear mines (mines will explode when shot)
- Can be used to blind/stun enemies for a short time. If you manage to shoot an enemy directly in the face, they will be stunned for a short period.
- Can be used to disable electronics silently. Just shoot at electronics and they will be disabled. This works on Communications Equipment (Radar Dishes), radio transmitters, power supplies etc.
- Can be useful against skulls. When shot, skulls will absorb the water, which stuns them briefly.
- > Can be used in the fight against the man on fire. It can stop him from doing some attacks. It's also possible to extinguish him, but that takes roughly 3-5 magazines.

Source: [Steam Guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=514013160)

Comment: A couple of less tactical usages include spraying Quiet for some extra fan-service, and squirting the crotch area of a napping enemy to trigger some additional funny dialog.

Comment: "Disable enemy electronics silently" is actually a big one. Thanks for the tip. Does it work on surveillance cameras? Also, I think it bears mentioning that it's intentionally a "useless" weapon for self-imposed challenges -- that's the kind of thing that would appeal highly to fans of the franchise (It appeals to me, anyway).

Comment: @LucasLeblanc Appeal to me too, was a great fan of PW's Banana Weapon, but it s better to know all uses : )

Comment: @DrakaSAN Of course the "useless" weapon is still going to have hidden uses, that's just Kojima's nature. I'm excited to see what he'll do next since he's finally free of Konami's ball-and-chain (even before certain recent events, he's always said that he intended his next iteration of Metal Gear to be the last). Not that I dislike MGS (obviously), but it's hard to see someone with Kojima's talent completely tied to it because he's afraid some money-grubbing dunce will replace him if he leaves.

Comment: @LoboDemon What are you talking about? That's highly tactical! You can't grab "naturally" sleeping soldiers -- hitting their fatigues wakes them up so you can grab them (presumably to put them back to sleep!)